# Blog has problems with html5 code

Tags: html, blogs, blogger, w3c

I know near to nothing of html, but I do maintain a blog.

I want that blog to be on bloglovin, but they tell me the RSS feed is not valid. What they give me is this tool that "checks" my code

[here](http://help.bloglovin.com/knowledgebase/articles/214416-i-m-unable-to-claim-my-blog) the instructions.

[here](http://validator.w3.org/) the tool.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmisbollosyotrascosas.blogspot.com.es%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

So main problem is, I dont know what doctype my blog has, nor I've been able to find info about it, so I don't know if checking said code on html5 is correct, or no. It's set to "detect automatically" so I'd guess it's getting it right, but I can't really be sure.

So, 1st problem: I don't know how to check the doctype.

2nd and more important, IF it has guessed the doctype properly, and it is html5, when I look for the piece of code the tool says it's wrong, said code does not appear. So I can't change code that isn't there.

Please mind 90% of the code is auto-generated, I do know programming, just not on web.

If anyone can point me of a way to fix this issue, much appreciated.

Comment: "I know near to nothing of html" You must demonstrate a minimal understanding, etc, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you nothing about HTML, then brother you first need to either learn HTML and then come here for help. Or you should go to the forum or the place provided by the CMS (Blog service provide) for the users to chat about the product usage.

However, the DOCTYPE is provided in the very first line. If you open Document Inspector, you'll see a grey line in Chrome as: `<!doctype html>`. That is the declaration for HTML5.

Here is the w3.org's doc for the HTML syntax: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html

And here is the declaration for the doctype: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype

Secondly, if they didnot find the document to meet the standards for the HTML5 then there might have been an error.

On the page, where you tested your DOCUMENT's code. They provided you with 113 errors in your document.

Please go and edit and fix them one after the other. To get help, go and Google the problem. 99% problems are solved by just Googling the problem and following the first 5 links if first 4 don't work. Otherwise, you can come back here and start a new question related to that problem. Programmers here would help you in doing that.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I wanted to do, people take for granted I want to bother or ... If a debugger tells me where the problem is, and tell me how to fix it, I am going to do it, and the tool from w3c does exactly that.

The problem is that the code the debugger is giving me, is either somewhere Im not looking, or... Don't know, but many of the 113 errors don't appear in my code. Is not "my code" but the code when I click on the button "html" on the blog gives me. So yeah, I just wanted to know where the doctype could be, what shoul be written there, and such. Can't learn html just 4 that

Comment: Brother you need to learn a language just for using it. If you dont know a language you wont be able to develop apps in it. A blog is an example for that.